# Returning minimum X numbers of a numpy array and keeping the order

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following X numpy array. I want to create an array from X[i] with the three minimum X[i][3] values of the array.

```
array([[  2, 356,   1, 0.7],
       [  3, 356,   1, 5],
       [  3, 357,   1, 3],
       [  4, 355,   1, 0.1],
       [  4, 356,   1, 16],
       [  4, 357,   1, 2]])
```

The result should look like:

```
array([[  2, 356,   1, 0.7],
       [  4, 355,   1, 0.1],
       [  4, 357,   1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach -

```
X[np.sort(X[:,3].argsort()[:3])]
```

Basically, we use `argsort` to get the sorted indices, select the first three for the lowest three elements. We will index the array with these indices for the output. To keep order as in the input array, sort those indices before indexing.

Sample run -

```
In [148]: X
Out[148]: 
array([[  2.00e+00,   3.56e+02,   1.00e+00,   7.00e-01],
       [  3.00e+00,   3.56e+02,   1.00e+00,   5.00e+00],
       [  3.00e+00,   3.57e+02,   1.00e+00,   3.00e+00],
       [  4.00e+00,   3.55e+02,   1.00e+00,   1.00e-01],
       [  4.00e+00,   3.56e+02,   1.00e+00,   1.60e+01],
       [  4.00e+00,   3.57e+02,   1.00e+00,   2.00e+00]])

In [149]: X[np.sort(X[:,3].argsort()[:3])]
Out[149]: 
array([[  2.00e+00,   3.56e+02,   1.00e+00,   7.00e-01],
       [  4.00e+00,   3.55e+02,   1.00e+00,   1.00e-01],
       [  4.00e+00,   3.57e+02,   1.00e+00,   2.00e+00]])
```

For performance, we can use [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). So, `X[:,3].argsort()[:3]` could be replaced by `np.argpartition(X[:,3],3)[:3]`. `argpartition` because of the way its implemented gives us the indices corresponding to the lowest `3` elements, just not necessarily in the order of lowest to second-lowest to third-lowest. But that's okay, as we would sort those indices anyway later on to keep the order as in the input array (discussed earlier).

Timings on the performance-boost suggestion -

```
In [164]: X = np.random.rand(100000,4)

In [165]: np.sort(X[:,3].argsort()[:3])
Out[165]: array([ 9950, 69008, 76552])

In [166]: np.sort(np.argpartition(X[:,3],3)[:3])
Out[166]: array([ 9950, 69008, 76552])

In [167]: %timeit np.sort(X[:,3].argsort()[:3])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.59 ms per loop

In [168]: %timeit np.sort(np.argpartition(X[:,3],3)[:3])
1000 loops, best of 3: 290 µs per loop
```

Comment: congrats on 100k  ♪(*^ ・^)ノ⌒ｵﾒﾃﾞﾄ☆

Comment: @EdChum Congrats on your 100k too. Epic! :)

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. Is sorting necessary? I don't care if they are sorted, it was done by pure chance.

Comment: @NorhanAhmad If you don't care, skip the `np.sort` part, but I guess its good to know that we could have the order kept by just adding a `sort` there.

Comment: @NorhanAhmad Looks like you haven't accepted any solution to any of your questions yet. So, let me introduce you to accepting solutions. If your question has been answered/solved, consider accepting one of the solutions by clicking on the green tick next to the solution. Read about it in more details here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work